# How to add integer offset to page number from \pageref{SomeLabel}?

Tags: pdfpages, pageref

I am using the `pdfpages` package to include 3 pages in my document.  I cannot put a `\label{}` command right on one of the pages because all 3 pages are represented by a single `\includepdf` command.  I can put a `\label{}` on the page immediately preceding the `\includepdf` command, but I would have to add an offset to the page number generated by `\pageref{}`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add numbered labels on the right pages. This is better than calculating (which is possible too) as the links would be correct too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{doc}
\begin{document}
\pageref{doc1}, \pageref{doc10}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{doc}\label{doc\thedoc}}]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Like frougon's answer yours was extremely educational in terms of delving into LaTeX counters.  I haven't been able to figure out a particular aspect of your solution.  The counter `doc` is incremented for each imported page.  I thought the counter would be wrong if the importation starts on (say) page 9 of the host document.  But the counter is correct.  Why is that?

Comment: the counter starts with 0 and is increased for each page. But you can change this if you want. The main point is to have a different label on every page.

Comment: Doesn't the `\refstepcounter` only increment the counter for each *included* page?  If page inclusion starts at (say) page 9 of the main document, I would have expected the first included page to have a value of 1 when it should be 10. Somehow, this is avoided, meaning that the counter is at the right value even for the first included page.

Comment: @user2153235 that's because the counter is used to *name the label*; for example, the included page (which is at page 9) has the label `doc1`. When resolving the reference `doc1`, LaTeX find it at page 9 --- *et voilá*

Answer (score 4):

The `refcount` package allows one to retrieve `\ref` as well as `\pageref` values in an *expandable* manner. This way, they can be used in many contexts, including in `\numexpr` computations:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

This is page 1.\newpage             % whatever

\label{second}\refused{second}%
This is page 2. Three pages after here is number~%
\the\numexpr \getpagerefnumber{second} + 3\relax.

\end{document}
```

On page 2:

[image]

Comment: Thank, frougon.  That was one heck of a jaunt through LaTeX commands that are new to me.  I wasn't able to find an explanation that I could understand for the `\refused` command (including the `\refcount` documentation).  Is there an elaboration online?

Comment: `\refused` is useful to generate the warning that tells LaTeX must be run again. Contrary to the expandable commands provided by the `refcount` package, it cannot be used in expansion-only contexts such as inside `\edef` or `\numexpr`.

Comment: Thanks again, frougon.