# Write pageref to a file

Tags: expansion

How to write `\pageref` to a file.

I've tried also with and without `\unexpanded\expandafter` with no success. And with `\immediate` as well.

I'd expect `19`. But I get `\pageref {mylabel}` or `\__cmd_start:nNNnnn {s}\pageref  \pageref code {\__cmd_grab_t:w *}{}{}{mylabel}` instead

**Note:** I open and close the file at the beginning resp. at the end of the document because I need to collect different data of the document.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newwrite\mytextfile

\begin{document}

\pageref{mylabel}

\openout\mytextfile=mytextfile.txt
\write\mytextfile{\pageref{mylabel}}
% outputs "\pageref {mylabel}"
\write\mytextfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\pageref{mylabel}}}
% outputs "\__cmd_start:nNNnnn {s}\pageref  \pageref code {\__cmd_grab_t:w *}{}{}{mylabel}"
\lipsum[1-99]
\label{mylabel}
\closeout\mytextfile

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is this `\unexpanded\expandafter{\pageref{mylabel}}` suppose to do?

Comment: \@daleif: Just trying as seen in other examples. Probably wrong way?

Comment: There is a package that provides an expandable `\pageref`-alternative, but I don't remember the package name...

Comment: Found it. See for example this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531768/117050 (instead of `\the\numexpr...` use the `\getpagerefnumber` macro in your `\write` statement).

Comment: \@Skillmon: Thanks. That was it!

Comment: \@Skillmon: This question has been answered thank to your comment. But it has not "formally" been answered yet. What is the appropriate next step, so that I can mark it as answered? a) you answer the question. b) I update the question and point to your comment. c) I answer the question and point to your comment. d) we wait until someone answers the question?

Comment: I'm wondering why this question has been closed. It is marked as duplicated to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531764/255699. IMHO it is not a duplicated. Even if in the other question there is a reference to the package `refcount` and this package offers an expandable way to access `\pageref`. But it doesn't explain that the reason why `\write` won't work with `\pageref` is because it is not expandable. Therefore I've voted for reopening. In my opinion this information doesn't need to be obfuscated.

Comment: @wolfrevo I'd like to post a formal answer (I agree that, while for an experienced programmer the information necessary to answer your question is in the linked thread, it is not really a duplicate). I voted to reopen, once it is reopened I can post an answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your purpose?  The aux file has `\newlabel{mylabel}{{}{19}}`, which contains the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `\pageref` as implemented by LaTeX is not expandable, but defined using the e-TeX `\protected` mechanism. As such it doesn't expand inside of `\message` or `\write` or `\edef` etc.

However, the package `refcount` defines an expandable command to get the page of a label, `\getpagerefnumber`. That can be used to write the page to a file. To also get warnings on undefined labels in the log you should use `\refused` (has to be used outside of your `\write` in a context where unexpandable stuff can happen). The following puts both into a single macro (if you need to write more to the file than the page number you should either put `\refused` outside the `\write` yourself, or include that in your macros).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newwrite\mytextfile

\NewDocumentCommand\writepagereftofile{mm}
  {%
    \refused{#2}%
    \write#1{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\pageref{mylabel}% if this wasn't used you should use `\refused` (an additional `\refused` doesn't hurt though)

\openout\mytextfile=mytextfile.txt
\writepagereftofile\mytextfile{mylabel}
\lipsum[1-99]
\label{mylabel}
\closeout\mytextfile

\end{document}
```

Comment: \@Skillmon: Thank you! Specially for the hint to `\refused`. BTW where is it documented?

Comment: @wolfrevo in the documentation of `refcount`.